# Imported mesh doesn't show its UV map

Tags: uv

I imported this mesh from a game and no matter if I open the image or UV editor it won't show its UV map. The image texture is assigned and it worked on other meshes from the game

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: File > External Data > Pack Resources

Comment: uploaded that thang

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=pas8mYPG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pas8mYPG/)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you've lost the UVs, you need to unwrap again, you can either mark some seams, or even simpler, use the *Project from View* option and align the UVs with the image, example:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!